# Inner Array with dynamic array naming

Tags: php, mysql

How can i make an array display like this selection from database:

```
$product_array = array(
  "1" =>array('product_id'=>'100', 'product_name'=>'Apple MacBook Pro MA464LL/A 15.4" Notebook PC','product_desc'=>'The Intel Core Duo powering MacBook Pro is actually two processors built into a single chip.', 'product_price'=>'2299.99', 'product_img'=>'products/product1.jpg'),
  "2" =>array('product_id'=>'101', 'product_name'=>'Sony VAIO 11.1" Notebook PC','product_desc'=>'Weighing in at just an amazing 2.84 pounds and offering a sleek, durable carbon-fiber case in charcoal black. And with 4 to 10 hours of standard battery life, it has the stamina to power you through your most demanding applications.', 'product_price'=>'2699.99', 'product_img'=>'products/product6.jpg'),
  "102" =>array('product_id'=>'102', 'product_name'=>'Canon Digital Rebel XT 8MP Digital SLR Camera','product_desc'=>'Canon EOS Digital Rebel XT SLR adds resolution, speed, extra creative control, and enhanced comfort in the hand to one of the smallest and lightest digital cameras in its class.', 'product_price'=>'550.00', 'product_img'=>'products/product3.jpg'),
  "3" =>array('product_id'=>'103', 'product_name'=>'HTC Touch Diamond','product_desc'=>'Re-defining the perception of advanced mobile phones… the HTC Touch Diamond™ signals a giant leap forward in combining hi-tech prowess with intuitive usability and exhilarating design.', 'product_price'=>'750.00', 'product_img'=>'products/product4.jpg'),
  "5" =>array('product_id'=>'104', 'product_name'=>'Apple iMac G5 Desktop','product_desc'=>'IMAC G5/1.8 256MB 160GB SD 20IN OS10.3', 'product_price'=>'1600.00', 'product_img'=>'products/product2.jpg'),
  "4" =>array('product_id'=>'105', 'product_name'=>'Blackberry 8900','product_desc'=>'', 'product_price'=>'1150.00', 'product_img'=>'products/product5.jpg'),
  "106" =>array('product_id'=>'106', 'product_name'=>'Headphone with mic','product_desc'=>'', 'product_price'=>'148.85', 'product_img'=>'products/product8.jpg'));
```

this is what i tried and its only displaying the last inner array element;

```
$getcat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product")or die('Error');
    $bk = array();
    $bdata = array();
    $data = array();
    while($get = mysql_fetch_array($getcat))
    {
    extract($get);
    $data[] = $get["product_id"];
    for($i=0;$i<= count($data);$i++){
    $bdata = array($i =>($bk[] = array('id'=>$product_id,'name'=>($product_name),'dew'=>$product_desc,'price'=>$product_price,'img'=>$product_img)));         }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Where should the outer array get its index from? Sometimes it's product_id, but often not.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this and see if it helps

```
$getcat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product")or die('Error');
    $bk = array();
    $bdata = array();
    $data = array();
    while($get = mysql_fetch_array($getcat))
    {
    extract($get);
    $data[] = $get["product_id"];
    for($i=0;$i<= count($data);$i++){
    $bdata[$product_id] = array($i =>array('id'=>$product_id,'name'=>($product_name),'dew'=>$product_desc,'price'=>$product_price,'img'=>$product_img));         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to display the data in a table:

```
<table border="1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th><b>ID</b></th>
        <th><b>Name</b></th>
        <th><b>Desc</b></th>
        <th><b>Price</b></th>
        <th><b>IMG</b></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
    foreach($product_array as $product){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $product["product_id"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $product["product_name"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $product["product_desc"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $product["product_price"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $product["product_img"] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: That's a possible interpretation of a vague question. :)

Answer (score 0):

The smallest code I can come up with to get close to the `$product_array` you describe is:

```
$getcat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product")or die('Error');
$product_array = array();
while($get = mysql_fetch_array($getcat);
    $product_array[] = $get;
vardump($product_array);
```

the indexes are different, be the same as what you tried to do with `$bdata`.

The error in your code is that you *overwrite* `$bdata` in every cycle of the while with a new array. That is why you only see the last inner array. You could fix that like this:

```
    $bdata[$i] = $bk[] = array('id'=>$product_id,'name'=>($product_name),'dew'=>$product_desc,'price'=>$product_price,'img'=>$product_img);
```

All the extra arrays and counting look very inefficient to me. And your use of [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) can make a mess of your symbol table.